# Will_Paginate pagination links missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, will-paginate

I have set-up will_paginate to paginate an array (list of customer orders) and am using the following code in my show view (the orders are nested on the seller's page);

```
<ol>
<% @seller.trans.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 6).each do |buy| %>
  <li><%= buy.customer.name %>£<%= buy.sum %><%= buy.date %></li>
<% end %>
</ol>
```

This has placed the right restriction on the array (6 per page) and I can manually filter through by changing the page number to 1, 2 or 3 (I have 13 orders) but the 'Next/Previous' links are missing from the view.

What is it I'm doing incorrectly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the code should be something like this

```
<ol>
  <% @buys = @seller.trans.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 6) %>
  <% @buys.each do |buy| %>
    <li><%= buy.customer.name %>£<%= buy.sum %><%= buy.date %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
<%= will_paginate(@buys) %>
```

take a look at the man page of the will_paginate gem from here, https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you :-) (I can't upvote due to my amatuerishness rep rating!)

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so this is how I would go about it:

**View:**

```
<%= will_paginate @seller, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

**Controller:**

```
@seller = *Model*.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6);
```

This has been tested using the gem **will_paginate-bootstrap**

Good luck!